# How to reference from iframe to web service with react.js

Tags: reactjs, iframe, reference, cross-domain

We have to add eventListener from iframe to real service(button)

i can handle only iframe(react.js) and we cannot handle both of service due to cross-domain issue.

So i just tried with createRef in react.js but i can't reference outside of iframe.

[image]

```js
import { createRef, useEffect } from "react";

const App = props => {
  const selectChildReference = createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // This thing will be undefined
    console.log(
      selectChildReference?.current?.ownerDocument?.defaultView?.document?.getElementsByClassName(
        "OgETmrvExa"
      )
    );
  }, [selectChildReference]);

  return (
    <div ref={selectChildReference} className="parent">
      <div className="app__main">
        <h3>React Project</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `useRef` hook instead of the `createRef` and add your listener methods onto the `selectChildReference.current`.